# How to merge multiple files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My files are in txt format and I wrote a short code to merge all three into a single one. Input files are (1) 18.8MB with over 16K columns, (2) 18.8MB with over 16K columns and (3) 10.5MB with over 7K columns. The code works, however it only merges first two files and creates output file. The data from the third input file is not included. What is wrong here and is there any limit regarding the size for txt files?

```
filenames = ['/Users/icalic/Desktop/chr_1/out_chr1_firstset.txt', '/Users/icalic/Desktop/chr_1/out_chr1_secondset.txt', '/Users/icalic/Desktop/chr_1/out_chr1_thirdset.txt']
with open('/Users/icalic/Desktop/chr1_allfinal.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
       with open(fname) as infile:
           for line in infile:
               outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Are you sure your 3rd file isn't empty or something as your code does appear to be correct - although faraz's answer is a great alternative. Any reason you're concatenating three different files with what sounds like are wildly differing columns - that doesn't seem a terrific idea...

Comment: Ninja is correct, your code is doing exactly what you want it to, about the only way you get nothing written from */Users/icalic/Desktop/chr_1/out_chr1_thirdset.txt* is if there is nothing in there to write.

Comment: Thanks guys, but my third file is not empty. I am still not getting complete dataset merged.

Comment: Add some `print` statements in the loop, just to make sure the code is doing what you expect based on the files. As all mention, the code looks right, so it might have some to do with the specific data files you are using. I know that logging with `print` statements is not the best option, but for such a simple case I think it will be enough.

Also, try to just use the third file in the `filenames` list, see if that gets indeed saved out... It becomes an exercise in debugging: tedious but useful.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) from the standard library:

```
import fileinput

filenames = [ '...' ]
with open(output_file, 'w') as file_out, fileinput.input(filenames) as file_in:
    file_out.writelines(file_in)
```

If you ever need finer control over memory use or need to handle binaries, use `shutil.copyfileobj`:

```
filenames = [ '...' ]
buffer_length = 1024*1024*10 # 10 MB

with open('output_file.txt', 'wb') as out_file:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as in_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(in_file, out_file, buffer_length)
```

Comment: The OP's own code should work as is so not sure this is going to make any difference as it is basically doing the exact same thing so the problem lies elsewhere.